# Unable to send custom data attribute in flutter_intercom

Tags: dart, flutter, intercom, intercom-ios

I am using [intercom_flutter](https://github.com/ChangeFinance/intercom_flutter) package to integrate the intercom in my mobile app. The application is working fine and I am able to update the default user information (`data attributes`). However, unable to update the custom information (`custom data attributes`). Please guide me if you guys faced and resolved the same issue. I also created an [issue](https://github.com/ChangeFinance/intercom_flutter/issues/2) in the `intercom_flutter` package as well.

*Note:* Referred below links as well

- https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/ios-configuration
- https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/android-configuration
- [Intercom.io Custom Attributes for Swift aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187287/intercom-io-custom-attributes-for-swift-arent-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished [a pull request](https://github.com/ChangeFinance/intercom_flutter/pull/6) which solves this issue.  Until the github repo owner accepts the request and publishes the updates, you can use a [dependency override](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides) to use this updated version.  Your `pubspec.yaml` would look a little something like:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intercom_flutter: ^1.0.8

dependency_overrides:
  intercom_flutter:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/cdoe/intercom_flutter.git
      ref: 0a745c3850a1011ca52a08be6d753fdc4c2c00d3
```

Let me know how this works for you.  I quickly tested on both iOS and Android, and it seems to be working swell!

Comment: CDoe, Can you add these methods as well setInAppMessagesVisible, unreadConversationCount?